# create-react-app not working 'A template was not provided'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, templates, npm, create-react-app

Hi there I'm having some problem with create-react-app:

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

added 1376 packages, and audited 1377 packages in 22m

181 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

6 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

**A template was not provided**. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

I have tried the recomendation steps from the create-react-app official website:
**npm uninstall -g create-react-app** - This didn't work.

I have clear the **npm cache**, also didn't work.

I have search with '**where create-react-app**' so I can delete it, and it didn't fine anything.

Can anybody help me with this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found, after trying lots similar answers was the following:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm cache clean --force
npx create-react-app@latest your-app-name
```

Notice the "@latest" create-react-app.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the solutions I found all over. Finally after a lot of hours I found this solution which worked on my Mac.

**Go to Macintosh HD > Users > "your user name" > node_modules**

If you have a folder with name ***create-react-app*** just delete it.

This worked for me and now I don't need to add the @latest every time I create a new React app.